# How does this file descriptor and flock work?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, flock

I want to implement a shell script to run in the background at all times. The script will
be added it in startup apps for running. While trying to make sure that only one instance runs at a time, I came across this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
another_instance()
{
echo “There is another instance running, exiting”
exit 1
}
( flock -n 100 || another_instance DEST=/home/backup/`date +%s` mkdir -p “$DEST” rsync -avz root@myhost:/home/web “$DEST/.” ) 100>/var/lock/dobackup.lock
```

[here](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/bash-ensure-instance-running), with the explanation:

*In this example, we use the file descriptor 100 in the redirection to the lock file. Also, we call another_instance if flock fails, informing there is another instance and then exiting.*

It works, but I do not understand the file descriptor 100 part. I tried looking online, but my confusion prevails.
Could someone please explain the `flock -n 100` and `100>/var/lock/dobackup.lock`?

As far as I understand, flock -n creates/checks for a lock at the given /var/lock.. location, but what's the significance of 100?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> flock -n creates/checks for a lock at the given /var/lock.. location

No, flock works on file descriptors.

`/var/lock` is a typical location for *system administrators* to put locks for *global utilities*. Like for example for package managers (`pacman`, `apt-get` etc.). You can use (ok, almost) any file anywhere with `flock`.

Let's say generally, `flock` is a *property* associated with a *file* referenced by a *file descriptor*. The number `100` is not significant, it has to be any open for writing file descriptor.

`100>/var/lock/dobackup.lock` redirects file descriptor `100` to file `/var/lock/dobackup.lock`. `flock -n 100` applies flock on the file descriptor `100`. When file descriptor `100` is closed (which happens when process terminates) then flock associated with that process is lifted automatically.

See Wikipedia for file descriptor, see `man 2 flock` and `man 2 fcntl`.